# Uploading files with Selenium Webdriver 2.53.0 in IE11

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have this issue:

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed.

with uploading files with Selenium in IE11 + WebDriver 2.53.0. Firefox works with this code corretly!

I tried things like threadsleep and wait, but nothing helps. I also tried thing like a click on the element (button) and then sendkeys, but it also doesn't work.

here is my HTML:

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
  <div class="input-group-btn" data-bind="unblocked: CanUploadApplicationDocuments">
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">Browse
      <input type="file" id="ApplicationDocumentsUpload" data-bind="event: { change: ApplicationFilesUploaded }" name="ApplicationDocumentsUpload" multiple="multiple"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ApplicationDocumentsUploadText" readonly>
</div>
```

here is my Selenium:

```
var dataCvPath = ResourceProvider.Provide(@"\Resources\CV\dataCV.docx");
var upload = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ApplicationDocumentsUpload"));
upload.SendKeys(dataCvPath);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you able to click on the button using IE. Refer to [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722790/ie-11-clicks-on-a-button-and-waits-until-time-out-selenium-webdriver), might be helpful. It is my question regarding pop up in IE11. If that doesn't help you, please let me know. Hope I can help you in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are providing the full path to `SendKeys`:

```
string dataCvPath = Path.GetFullPath(ResourceProvider.Provide(@"\Resources\CV\dataCV.docx"));
if (!File.Exists(dataCvPath))
    throw new Exception("File not found: " + dataCvPath);

var upload = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ApplicationDocumentsUpload"));
upload.SendKeys(dataCvPath);
```

Note that if you are working with a remote session, you also need to set the file detector:

```
driver.FileDetector = new LocalFileDetector();
```