# Selenium a href="javascript:;" Click Not Working on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I have got a Selenium test code to click a hfref and open a new tab on browser. a tag is like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="redirectToLms"><strong>Click</strong></a>
```

Below test code is working on Chrome Browser successfully and open a new tab and page but is not working on Internet Explorer 11. Selenium can't click and open new tab. Test fails.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("redirectToLms")).click();
```

How can I can click that a tag with selenium on IE 11?

Comment: Do you get an exception or just nothing happens?

Comment: Nothing happens. I expect click and open a new page in a new tab. But Nothing happens. Selenium doesn't say anything or throw any exception.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722790/ie-11-clicks-on-a-button-and-waits-until-time-out-selenium-webdriver) might help.

Comment: Have you tried to use .is_displayed() (python example) to check if the iedriver can actually find the element? Otherwise try with xpath. It would be something like: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='redirectToLms']")).click()

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hello. @Sudeepthi, that link didn't help me.
MSJ Xpath is not solution for this. I tried but nothing happens again.

Comment: Did it work in any other browser. Try explicit wait `new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.id("redirectToLms"))).click();`

Comment: @Sudeepthi, This operation works on Chrome perfectly. In IE Selenium clicks link but doesn't affect.
I think Selenium thinks "I clicked" but IE not open new tab and page.